If a large table is created from another large table, is that new table saved as a separate entity, or a reference to the original table?
In my scenario, I have a very large dataset with over 25 million rows (call it table B), and that is created from another table that is even larger (call it table A). I have stored this new table B as its own table on redshift.
Recently, a bunch of data is deleted in table A from IT, and I realised the data is also deleted in table B, which made me suspect table B is a query of some sort to table A. Is this a reasonable assumption? Does redshift do this if the tables are too large? I have not observed the same thing in other smaller tables.
Please excuse my lack of knowledge on servers and databases, there's much I'm still learning. Thanks.

How do you create B from A? Are you sure B is not a real-table not a view?

Views, Cascading deletes ( if you have fancy foreign keys ), triggers.  When you say "B Created from A".  Is that a projection, is someone doing a "SELECT * INTO B WHERE xxx ".  I think you need to get the schema information for A and B to see what kind of object it is.

The table is created in R (which auto translates to SQL) so I can't say exactly what the SQL commands were, but in R it would be an extended version of something like this:
table_b <- table_a %>% filter(some_variable > 100) %>% compute("table_B") 
Edit: I have just found the machine translated SQL code, it looks something like this :
CREATE TABLE table_b (col_1 CHARACTER VARYING(32) ENCODE LZO, col_2 BIGINT ENCODE AZ64);

So if it is a create table, then it is a new table saved as a separate entity.

This doesn't look like sql server though?
